# Receiving a string as a void pointer parameter and using strcpy to change it

Tags: c

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void print (void*);

int main (void)
{
  char *a = "Mcwhat";
  print(&a);
  printf("\n%s", a);
  return 0;
}

void print (void *text)
{
    char* pchar[5];

    *pchar = (char*)text;

    strcpy( *pchar, "Mcthat" );
}
```

I am trying to make Mcwhat into Mcthat using a void parameter, but the printf gives me a segmentation fault afterwards. Where is my mistake? I managed to do it char by char but now I want to change the whole string. Didn't found enough material on this in the books on C I have.

Comment: Using `void *` is a bad idea. You remove a lot of capabilities of the compiler in one swoop

Comment: Why must you people downvote me? It's a good question, there's no similar in the site and only limited people were able to answer it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep it simple and pay attention to the type of your variables :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void print (void*);

int main()
{
  char a[] = "Mcwhat"; // a is now a read-write array
  print(a); // a decays to a pointer, don't take its adress or you'll get a pointer-to-pointer
  printf("\n%s", a);
  return 0;
}

void print (void *text)
{
    strcpy( text, "Mcthat" ); // Don't dereference text here
}
```

Note that this "print" function is unsafe in all imaginable ways, but that wasn't the question.

Answer (score 1):

There are lot of issues in your code:
1. Char array should be big enough to store the string. `char[5]` cannot hold Mswhat.
2. `char* pchar [5]` declares 5 char pointers, whereas you need one char pointer pointing to a char array.

I have corrected it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void print (char*);

int main (void)
{
  char *a = malloc(10);
  strcpy(a,"Mcwhat");
  print(a);
  printf("\n%s", a);
  free(a);
  return 0;
}

void print (char *text)
{
  char *pchar = text;
  strcpy( pchar, "Mcthat" );
}
```

Comment: Corrected ? You're obviously leaking memory. The two first lines of print don't even make sense, you're assigning the pointer two times.

Answer (score 0):

Just write it like that

```
void print (char *text)
{    
    strcpy( text,  "Mcthat" );
}
```

But make sure, the that size of `text` is large enough to put `"Mcthat"` inside it.

Also in `main`:

```
print(a);
```

instead of

```
print(&a);  // would requite void print (char** text)
```

tho whole shebang:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void print (void*);
int main (void)
{
  char *a = malloc(strlen("Mcwhat")+1);
  print(a);
  printf("\n%s\n", a);
  free(a);
  return 0;
}

void print (void *text)
{
    strcpy(text, "Mcthat" );
}
```

Comment: Segmentation Fault:
#0 004016F3 print(text=0x405064 <_Jv_RegisterClasses+4214884>) (E:\Projects and Documents\Programming\C\CodeBlocks\Tester #1\main.c:16)
#1 004016D2 main() (E:\Projects and Documents\Programming\C\CodeBlocks\Tester #1\main.c:9)

Comment: Edited to see the whole thing. No segfault, I tested.

Comment: This code writes 7 bytes into a 6 byte-long buffer.